# Multiple wildcard certificates on one IIS site?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

We already have an SSL certificate for *.foo.com pointing to an IIS site. Now we want to point *.bar.co.nz point to the same web application and will purchase another wildcard certificate.

Is it possible to set up two wildcard SSL certificates under the one IIS site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to include both domains in a single wildcard certificate (with the use of "subject alternative name"). For more information, see RobLL's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain).

Comment: Finding a CA that issues certificates with wildcards as SANs seems almost impossible. I'm thinking it'll be easier adding another IP address to the same binding and using a separate SSL certificate.

Comment: Well, by Googling for "Multi-Domain Wildcard SSL" I managed to find at least one company that offers such certificates.